# 'list::list' names the constructor, not the type

Tags: c++

I get this error while compiling my class linked list with constructors. I wanted to do a copy assignment operator, but i get this error 'list::list' names the constructor, not the type.
the line is:

```
list::list& operator= (const list &l)
```

list is my the name of my class

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This error is pretty self-explanatory.

Use this code:

```
list& operator= (const list &l)
```

Outside a class declaration, you have to precise in which scope belongs the function:

```
list& list::operator= (const list &l)
//    ^^^^^^
```

Comment: error: 'list& operator=(const list&)' must be a nonstatic member function

Comment: You're defining your `operator=` outside the class declaration. See my edit.

Answer (score 7):

If you are defining your `operator=` function *inside* your class definition, declare it thus:

```
class list {
  ...
  list& operator=(const list&) { ... return *this; }
};
```

If you are defining your `operator=` function *outside* your class definition, declare it as in this complete and correct example:

```
class list {
  public:
  list& operator=(const list&);
};
list& list::operator=(const list&) {
  return *this;
}
int main() {}
```

Comment: i declared it in the class and then when i want to give the codes outside the class i have used the given code and it gives me this error

Comment: alright this works, now i have to implement copy assignment operator for a linked list :/

Comment: Please remember to **upvote** all of the useful answers by clicking on the upward-facing triangle, and **accept** the best answer by clicking on the check mark.